# Ruby script in Logstash

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm running a ruby script in logstash to extract information from logs.

```
if [status] == "Txn posted on POS"
{
    ruby{
      init => "@@map = {}"
      code => "@@map['transactionStartTime'] = event.get('logTimestamp'),@@map['startTxnNumber'] = event.get('txnNumber'),@@map['startTillNumber'] = event.get('tillNumber')"
    }


}
else if [status] == "Txn persisted in MREP" 
{
  ruby{
        code => "if @@map['startTxnNumber'] == event.get('txnNumber')
                    event.set('startedTime', @@map['startTxnNumber'])
                 end"
      }
}
```

Due to some reason it's not coming in the if clause. I can't seem to understand the problem, there is no syntax error i'm sure

Comment: Can you show a sample log line that is supposed to trigger the if clause?

Comment: well it would be more difficult to understand if I show you the log but here you go :

Comment: Also can you add `stdout {codec=>rubydebug}` to your output section and show how the end event looks like

Comment: @Val, yeah i'm doing that in the output.

Comment: @Val is there any possibility I can debug this

Comment: Hard to say, I don't see anything I've asked for in my comments :-)

Comment: @Val i'm sorry
log: 
 "2017-10-13 08:15:33,032401900: DEBUG : [Camel (camelContext) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[jms/ETLPUBLISH]] com.pcmsgroup.v21.et
l.persistence.fact.transaction.TransactionLogDbDao: Result from database activity for parameter object {eventSequence=1, dateCreated=Fri Oct 13 0
8:15:33 BST 2017, eventType=1, transactionNumber=673, tillDescription=1, transactionDate=Fri Oct 13 08:15:29 BST 2017, storeCode=2571, companyCod
e=A001}: 1"

Comment: Update your question with 1) the log line that is supposed to work, 2) what you get from that log line in the `stdout` output

Comment: @Val I found the issue, these two fields which I was comparing although they had the same data but different datatypes, so it didn't compare them.
Thank you for helping, cheers.

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Comment: @Val i'm currently working on ELK as a junior developer, any possibility I can contact you on email.
I face a lot of problems and i'm learning everyday

Comment: The best is to create questions here on SO, so other people can also answer and/or benefit from your questions and their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem and fixed it.
The problem was because of datatype mismatch, the condition

```
if @@map['startTxnNumber'] == event.get('txnNumber')
```

txnNumber was a string and startTxnNumber was an int, so it was not comparing these values.